# Where is EntityConfiguration and ContextBuilder in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, poco

I see [examples](http://elegantcode.com/2009/12/15/entity-framework-poco-ef4-a-simple-mapping/) about code-only POCO for en entity framework 4, but I cannot find the classes EntityConfiguration and ContextBuilder and I cannot see which reference I need to add to have them.

Is it part of the .Net Framework 4 or do we have to download something else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The POCO stuff you're looking for is in a separate download. Current version is at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=af18e652-9ea7-478b-8b41-8424b94e3f58&displayLang=en

Once you run the installer, you'll need to grab the Microsoft.Data.Entity.CTP.dll file (mine was in the C:\Program Files\Microsoft ADO.NET Entity Framework Feature CTP3\Binaries directory). Make a project reference to the new dll and you should be set!

Comment: Ok yip it is still the latest as at 7th May 2010

Comment: CTP 4 is now out: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4e094902-aeff-4ee2-a12d-5881d4b0dd3e&displaylang=en

Comment: Please see this [More Recent Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633619/where-is-entityconfiguration-in-ef4-vs-2010-rtm)