# Where is EntityConfiguration in EF4 VS 2010 RTM?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, code-first

I cannot find EntityConfiguration.

The same question for RC was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337057/where-is-entityconfiguration-and-contextbuilder-in-visual-studio-2010-rc) but I thought that it would make it to the RTM version. Is it there?

Comment: @William Chang: I agree with your answer (deleted now). Tried yesterday to go with "code-only" on RTM couldn't believe it wasn't there. Only as a community preview you're kidding right? In my book the product (EF) is blatantly not finished and is not ready for use. I dropped my plans to go with it.

Comment: In general, I have to say the last couple of years MS team has been doing lots of mess. Current major products (Visual Studio, SQL Server) incompatible with their current operating systems. Little add-ons like MVC and Database Projects (GDR) crash during installation unless you install all that stuff and service packs in a very specific order which is nowhere specified. It had a very painful experience. You should work better. There is no point in producing that much of crap if none is properly finished.

Comment: CTP is a technology PREVIEW. People often complain they weren't actively involved in helping shape the product to what they wanted and CTP's are exactly that process. It isn't in RTM because it wasn't ready and it isn't go live yet because the API is still under active development based on the feedback the team has been getting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EntityConfiguration<>** is **EntityTypeConfiguration<>**

**UPDATE 7**
[EF 4.1 Released](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/ef-4-1-released)

**UPDATE 6**
[Microsoft ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.1 Release Candidate (EF 4.1 RC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/ef-4-1-release-candidate-available) with go-live license is out.

**EntityConfiguration<> is** from CTP5 **EntityTypeConfiguration<>**

**UPDATE 5**

> Our plan is to deliver a Go-Live
> Release Candidate version of the
> DbContext API and Code First in mid to
> late March. This Release Candidate
> will be titled **ADO.NET Entity
> Framework 4.1**. Approximately a month
> after the RC ships we plan to release
> the final Release to Web (RTW).

[EF 4.1 Is Coming (DbContext API & Code First RTW)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160612000626/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/archive/2011/03/02/ef-4-1-is-coming-dbcontext-api-amp-code-first-rtw.aspx)

**UPDATE 4**
[EF Feature CTP5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/ef-feature-ctp5-released)
[Announcing Entity Framework Code-First (CTP5 release)](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/announcing-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-release)
[EF Feature CTP5: Code First Walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/ef-feature-ctp5-code-first-walkthrough)
[EF Feature CTP5: Model & Database First with DbContext](https://web.archive.org/web/20160610094639/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/archive/2010/12/06/ef-feature-ctp5-model-amp-database-first-with-dbcontext.aspx)
[EF Feature CTP5: Fluent API Samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/ef-feature-ctp5-fluent-api-samples)
[Looking at EF4 CTP5 in Parts: Part 1 - A New T4 Template](https://thedatafarm.com/data-access/looking-at-ef4-ctp5-in-parts-part-1-a-new-t4-template/)
[Looking at EF4 CTP5 in Parts: Part 2–Internal Validation](https://web.archive.org/web/20130922210906/http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/looking-at-ef4-ctp5-in-parts-part-2-ndash-internal-validation/)
[Looking at EF4 CTP5 in Parts: Part 3–Easy Access to In-Memory Entities](https://thedatafarm.com/data-access/looking-at-ef4-ctp5-in-parts-part-3-easy-access-to-in-memory-entities/)
[Looking at EF4 CTP5 in Parts: Part 4–Working with New and Existing Databases in Code First](https://thedatafarm.com/data-access/looking-at-ef4-ctp5-in-parts-part-4working-with-new-and-existing-databases-in-code-first/)

**UPDATE 3**
[ADO.NET Entity Framework (EF) Feature Suggestions](https://web.archive.org/web/20190111182436/https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions)

**UPDATE 2**
[Entity Framework Feature CTP 4](https://web.archive.org/web/20160502104003/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/archive/2010/07/14/ctp4announcement.aspx) is out and available to [download](https://web.archive.org/web/20100821212259/http://www.microsoft.com:80/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4e094902-aeff-4ee2-a12d-5881d4b0dd3e&displaylang=en).

---

Finally found something. According to this [slideshow](https://www.slideshare.net/ericnelson/entity-framework-4-in-microsoft-visual-studio-2010) (slide 17) there will be a separate Feature Pack to download.

> Feature Pack Separate download
>
> Contents
>
> T4 Template for Persistence
>
> Ignorance/POCO T4 Template for self-tracking entities (Now part of VS2010 RC)
>
> Code-only support
>
> When VS2010 is RTM, Feature Pack will be high quality.

---

**UPDATE** - useful links:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/efdesign/)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723.aspx

Comment: Here is a direct link for the latest EF4 Feature CTP 3: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=AF18E652-9EA7-478B-8B41-8424B94E3F58

Comment: There is a little problem with CTP3. There is no go-live license see http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2010/02/18/entity-framework-feature-ctp-3-now-available.aspx

Comment: Any news on this Feature Pack?