# Entity Framework - ContextBuilder namespace

Tags: c#, entity-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is EntityConfiguration in EF4 VS 2010 RTM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633619/where-is-entityconfiguration-in-ef4-vs-2010-rtm)

I apologize if this seems like an excessively dumb question.

I am trying to use the ContextBuilderClass to generate my Context. I am unable to find the proper assembly and namespace to use it though.

Just for reference I am on a full install of VS 2010 Pro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked the team and here is their response:

Right now the Entity Framework Feature CTP contains the latest bits of Code-First and is compatible with EF4 RTM. Please, find it here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=af18e652-9ea7-478b-8b41-8424b94e3f58&displayLang=en.

Comment: when can we expect a full release? it's already been a long time since RTM