# Is EF4 "Code Only" ready for production use?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, code-first

I've been looking at the new Entity Framework 4 Code Only features, and I really like them. But I'm having a hard time finding good resource on the feature. Everything seems to be spread around blongs here and there, so this make me wonder if it's ready to be used for a serious project?

What do you think? Is it ready for production use or should I use the more traditional approach (EDMX designer, POCO objects)?

Also, I would like to know if there are any features that Code Only does not support yet, compared to the EDMX designer?

What do you think about the Code Only feature? Is it "mature" yet?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends when your project should be ready. Code First (Code Only) is only in CTP3 without go-live license. As I've read, there is no exact timeframe for the Feature Pack [Where is EntityConfiguration in EF4 VS 2010 RTM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633619/where-is-entityconfiguration-in-ef4-vs-2010-rtm) and it will be published when it will be ready (no release date). According to the blog of EF team it will be available in the next framework release.

> Code First is still under active
> development and will have some
> breaking changes so there is no
> go-live licence at this time.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/entity-framework-feature-ctp-3-now-available)

Code First = Code Only

In my projects I went with EF + POCO for now.

Comment: Yes, CTP4 is out for some time. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/07/14/ctp4announcement.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for an answer to this, Entity Framework V4.1 which has the "Code first" feature has been RTW (released to web) for production use since a month and a half now.

You need .Net 4.0 RTM in order to install it. Once you have that installed, you can download the stand-alone installer for EF4.1 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b41c728e-9b4f-4331-a1a8-537d16c6acdf&displaylang=en).